# Polyval issues after using polyint

Tags: matlab

Im trying to calculate the area of randomly generated graph, which is created from randomly generated x and y values and drawn using polyfit.

```
clear
clc

for i=1:8
    x(i)= round((12+5).*rand - 5,0)
    y(i)= round((7+6).*rand -6,0)
end



p=polyfit(x,y,5);
x1=-5:0.1:12;
y1=polyval(p,x1);

plot(x,y,'o')
hold on
plot(x1,y1)
y2=(x1)*0-5
plot(x1,y2)
hold off

syms x 
S1=int(x.*0-5,x,-2,7)
pp=polyint(p,x)
S2=polyval(pp,-2)-polyval(pp,7)
S=S1+S2
```

However, I am getting this weird error that doesnt make any sense to me.

```
Undefined function 'filter' for input arguments of type 'sym'.

Error in polyval (line 56)
    y = filter(1,[1 -x],p);
```

Why doesnt it allow me to use polyval after using polyint ? Its still a polynomial..

In other words. How could I change the end of the code to calculate the definite integral of the newly formed polynomial, which is always different

Comment: Or perhaps there is a better way to calculate the are of those two lines ? Cause its not going to always work with this method.

Comment: in polyint(p,k) k must be Scalar value but in your code k is x and x is symbolic variable because syms x